# $|c|+|a+b+c|$ versus $|a+c|+|b+c|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I need to compare

$$|c|+|a+b+c| \quad{\rm versus}\quad |a+c|+|b+c|.$$

I tried using the triangle inequality and have gotten nowhere in figuring out which expression is bigger.

Comment: Why do you think one is "bigger"?

Comment: Try it for $c=0, a=-b$ then for $a=b=-c$, and you'll get opposite answers.

Comment: Try it for a million random numbers a,b,c and count how often they are equal, or which side is greater.

Comment: I got them equal $55\%$ of the time, $|c|+|a+b+c|\gt |a+c|+|b+c|$, $20\%$ of the time, and $|c|+|a+b+c| \lt  |a+c|+|b+c|$, $25\%$ of the time.  That was with all three independently normal $N(0,1)$.  This conflicts with ApassJack because the change of variables makes them no longer independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do a bit of magic for fun.

Consider
$$|c|+|a+b+c| \quad{\rm versus}\quad |a+c|+|b+c|.$$
Let $a=-a'$, $b=b'$, $c=a'+c'$, where $a', b', c'$ are three arbitrary numbers. Then we are considering
$$|a'+c'|+|b'+c'| \quad{\rm versus}\quad |c'|+|a'+b'+c'|.$$

We have exchanged the two sides of the original comparison, with a different set of $3$ free variables. Hence, there cannot be a definitive lopsided result of the comparison.

---

On the other hand, in order to show neither side can be bigger/not smaller always, two simple examples such as follows are enough.

$$|0| + | 1+(-1)+0| < |1+0| + |(-1)+0|.$$
$$|-1|+|1+1+(-1)|>|1+(-1)|+|1+(-1)|.$$

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve such a question is to try to get the inside of an absolute value equal to zero.

For the first, this can easily be achieved by making sure that $a+b+c$ is zero, which you can reach, e.g., by $a=10c$ and $b=-9c$, so the expression $|c| + |a + b + c|$ equals $|c|$. The other expression $|a + c| + |b + c|$ then equals $19 |c|$, which is larger.

For the second, this can easily be achieved by making sure that both $a$ and $b$ equal $-c$. This makes the second expression zero and the first one becomes  $2 |c|$.

So, there is no standard relation between $|c|+|a+b+c|$ and $|a+c|+|b+c|$.

**Remark**:
You might react "*In order to make $|a+b+c|$ zero, I would opt for $a$ and $b$, both being $-\frac{c}{2}$*".
That might be interesting indeed, but there's absolutely no obligation for $a$ and $b$ to be equal. Always take this into account!